# change style of table's specific columns

Tags: css, asp.net, html-table

As you can see, I have two tables each inside two divisions . [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/XRnWj/) is jsFiddle example ! What I want to do is to change the background color of  `firstDiv`'s table first column and third column , `secondDiv`'s table second column and fourth column , By `CSS` only :)

```
<div id="firstDiv" style="float:left;margin-right:12px;">
<table width="200" border="1" cellpadding="8">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
     <div id="secondDiv">
<table width="200" border="1" cellpadding="8">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
       </div>
```

Comment: use `:nth-child` pseudo-selector? http://jsfiddle.net/XRnWj/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at typical usage of `nth-child` with even/odd selector.

Following should do the trick.

```
#firstDiv td:nth-child(odd)
{
    background-color:#cecece;
}
#secondDiv td:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color:#cecece;
}
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dU895/)

Another variation:-

```
#firstDiv td:nth-child(2n+1)
{
    background-color:#cecece;
}
#secondDiv td:nth-child(2n+2)
{
    background-color:#cecece;
}
```

If you want to specifically select 1st and 3 alone then you can use

```
#firstDiv td:nth-child(1), 
#firstDiv td:nth-child(3) {
    background-color:#cecece;
}
#secondDiv td:nth-child(2), 
#secondDiv td:nth-child(4) {
    background-color:#cecece;
}
```

See for [support](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child)

Comment: Thanks A.K and PSL :) , but I want to know more ! How can I access div with `class` instead of `id` ( <div class="firstDiv"> ) ?

Comment: It would be `.firstDiv` instead of `#firstDiv`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-child) pseudo-selector. [See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XRnWj/2/)

Answer (score 1):

**Edited:**

You can achive it by using `nth-child` also but all browser does not support `nth-child`

But the following approach is supported in all browsers..

**CSS:**

```
#firstDiv td,
#firstDiv td + td + td{
    background-color:#cecece;
}

#firstDiv td + td,
#firstDiv td + td + td + td{
    background-color:#fff;
}


#secondDiv td + td,
#secondDiv td + td + td + td{
    background-color:#cecece;
}

#secondDiv td,
#secondDiv td + td + td{
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8tFdX/)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to apply your CSS class to a relevant cell (e.g. 1st TD) of every row in the table. This way an impression will be given that entire column is of a different color. When setup like this if you change background color in CSS class definition - the change will affect all cells in the column at once.